# Input very small bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, input, modal-dialog

I use bootstrap and when i try to place an input i have this :

[image: input]

A very small input...

```
<!-- FILTRE 2em partie-->
<div id="filtre2" class="modal hide fade row-fluid" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="filtre2" aria-hidden="true">

    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h3 id="filtre2">Paramétre du filtre générique (2/2)</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body" class="form-horizontal" >
        <div class="rep"></div>
        <p>Lorsqu'un message correspondant à cette recherche arrive :</p>
        <em>Spécifier le sous-dossier dans lequel le mail doit être envoyé : </em>
        <input type="text" name="repertory" id="repertory"/>
        <!--<p><input type="checkbox"  name="spam" id="checksuppr" value="spam"/> Supprimer le message</p>-->
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Fermer</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id="creespam">Créer filtre</button>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: And what your question is?! Wanna increase the `input`'s size? Simply use `<input type="text" size="50" />`

Comment: @smhnaji size="50" Doesn't change anything

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In bootstrap, you can add classes to increase the length of the input control.  For example, `input-large`, `input-xlarge`, `input-xsmall`, etc...  You can also use `input-block-level` to have the input fill the width of the containing div.

You can see here for more details regarding form control styling:

http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/base-css.html#forms

Also, make sure you have your doctype specified as HTML5 using `<!DOCTYPE HTML>` and the meta tag is properly set, such as `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`.  While I have not had any issues with this, I've read that bootstrap can have some issues if these are not properly defined.

Good luck!

Comment: input-block-level save me ! thx :)

Comment: I couldn't make it work for bootstrap 3.x?